# RenderLoop vs Stage when using Juggler in StageXL

Tags: dart, stagexl

I am really new to StageXL, so still struggling with the basic concepts.  I have the following code from Stagehand web-stagexl:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:stagexl/stagexl.dart';
import 'dart:math';

Future<Null> main() async {
  var canvas = html.querySelector('#stage');
  var stage = new Stage(canvas, width: 1280, height: 800);

  var renderLoop = new RenderLoop();
  renderLoop.addStage(stage);

  var resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
  resourceManager.addBitmapData("dart", "images/dart@1x.png");
  await resourceManager.load();
  var logoData = resourceManager.getBitmapData("dart");

  var logo = new Sprite();
  logo.addChild(new Bitmap(logoData));
  stage.addChild(logo);

  var tween = renderLoop.juggler.addTween(logo, 3, Transition.easeOutBounce);
// var tween = stage.juggler... works just as well
  tween.animate.y.to(800 / 2);
}
```

At the bottom, we can use either var tween=stage.juggler or renderLoop.juggler and the code seems to behave the same.  The documentation can point to either way, but my understanding is that renderLoop is a stream, and not a node, and so stage.juggler makes more sense to me.  Is there a difference in use, and are there other instances where one is preferred to another?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the Stage.juggler or the RenderLoop.juggler. The Juggler from the RenderLoop is driven by the browser (see RequestAnimationFrame), and the Juggler from the Stage is driven by RenderLoop.juggler. So the Stage.juggler is more for your convenience. You can also create your own instance of Juggler and add the instance (since Juggler implements the Animatable interface) to the RenderLoop.juggler.

You can learn more about this here:
http://www.stagexl.org/docs/wiki-articles.html?article=juggler